# How i can hover image show mini gallery

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Hi, I want category image a hover show up product mini gallery like a tooltip**

### Exam

```
<div class="xxx"><img src="..." onhover="xx"><div class="gallery"><img src=".."><img src="xx"></div></div>
```

Comment: Your description of what is the issue and what you are trying to achive needs to be more clear, also please try to add a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your code, for us to debug and help you.

Answer (score 0):

there are many easiest option is attibut [title](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) or you can use [jqueryui/tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)